# How to make batch with pictures of different sizes for model in PyTorch?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I want to use GlobalAveragePooling in my PyTorch model and not to resize, crop or pad the image. I can train my model using only one image every iteration (not batch). But it is too slow and I don't know how to use several images of different sizes as one input for Model.
Example of model code:

```
class GAPModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    self.conv = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    )
    
    self.linear = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(in_features=16, out_features=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
    )

  def forward(self, image):
    return self.linear(self.conv(image).mean([2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to choose a image of the same size for each stack.
Caution.

1. shuffling: can group indexes/images_id by size and then apply shuffle within the group.
2. last batch: just do something similar to drop_last if neccessary (see torch dataloader)
3. maybe there is more work ...

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, when you train a model you provide it with your input data.
The shape of your input data looks like this:
channel_last:  `(batch_size, height, width, num_of_channels)` or channel_first: `(batch_size, num_of_channels, height, width)`
If **batch_size=32** (input_data.shape = `(32,height,width,channels)` , it means that all 32 images should have the same **height**, **width**, and **num_of_channels**.
Because you cannot store your input_data with different shapes into one *numpy_array* or *tensor*.
***More clarification:***
For example, if you have two different images, img_1 and img_2.
Their shapes are image1.shape=`224,224,3`, image2.shape=`288,288,3`, and you want to make **batch_of_imgs** with these two images. If so, what will be the shape of **batch_of_imgs** ?
Will it be batch_of_imgs.shape=`(2,224,224,3)` or `(2,288,288,3)` ?
As you see, when making a batch of images they should be the same shape.
 It means that your input data(*numpy_arrays* or *tensors*) should be rectangular, that is, rows(columns) of arrays in batch should be the same.

Comment: By resizing your images, you can get the same shape of images, and then you can batch them.